# Detect page zoom on iPad and hide particular classes

Tags: jquery, hide, zooming, show, tablet

I'm trying to detect if a user zooms on an iOS devise while using my website, if they zoom I would like to hide specific elements and likewise if they zoom out I want to show them again.

Is this possible?

I know this is a device feature rather than something browser or page specific but it seems like a problem with how the page looks and how certain elements resize and position.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this

```
var zoomOri = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
var zoomCurrent = zoomOri;
$(window).resize(function() {
 var zoomNew = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
 if (zoomOri != zoomNew && zoomNew != zoomCurrent) {
     $('.yourclas').hide();
 else if (zoomOri == zoomNew && zoomNew != zoomCurrent)
     $('.yourclas').show();
 zoomCurrent = zoomNew      
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've had a lot of people tell me you can't do this so it's really good to see that you can actually work around objects with fixed positions looking really bad when zoomed.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work on my iPad. How is a zoom a resize event?